# "command not found" is printed every time I open the terminal

Tags: bash, configuration

[image]

I was entering a command to solve a "permissions denied" error, so I used `nano` to edit some file that I don't remember.

Now, every time I open bash it displays

```
-bash: aliases.: command not found
-bash: ^X: command not found
```

How can I correct this?

Comment: FYI in the "hints" `^O`, `^X` etc. at the bottom of the `nano` editor screen, the `^` refers to the `Ctrl` key rather than a literal `^`

Answer (score 4):

One of your shell's startup files contains a command that is not found. The error message indicates that the command is `aliases.`.  Since this looks like the end of a sentence of *text* (not shell code) I'm assuming this is due to accidentally deleting a comment character (`#`) on some line in the file.

Have a look at either `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` or whatever other shell startup file that you have recently edited and look for the string `aliases.` in them, this may help you pinpoint the issue.